# Is there any symmetric complex matrix not satisfying this condition

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Friedberg linear algebra p.471:

"If $A$ is symmetric with entries in $\mathbb{F}$, then $||A||_{op}$ is the largest absolute value of $A$"

Here, the operator norm is defined as $||A||_{op} \triangleq \sup_{x\neq 0} \frac{||Ax||}{||x||}$.

==========

I can prove this sentence when the field is $\mathbb{R}$, but i'm not sure when $\mathbb{F}=\mathbb{C}$.

Let $A$ be a $n\times n$ symmetric complex matrix and $\lambda$ be an eigenvalue of $A$.

Then, $\overline{\lambda}$ is an eigenvalue of $A^*$, since $A$ is symmetric.

My question is, is $\lambda$ an eigenvalue of $A^* A$?

If not, please give me a counterexample.

Comment: Are you sure you are quoting Friedberg word for word? The phrase "the largest absolute value of $A$" sounds very weird. And what is $\mathbb{F}$? Is it either $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that for $\mathbb{F} = \mathbb{C}$, the author meant hermitian when (s)he wrote symmetric.

Over $\mathbb{C}$, symmetry in the sense of $A^T = A$ is not very interesting, and it's easy to find counterexamples. Let

$$A = \begin{pmatrix}i & 1\\1 & 0\end{pmatrix}$$

$A$ is obviously symmetric in the $A^T = A$ sense, the operator norm is $\sqrt{\frac52} = \lVert A\cdot\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(-i,1)\rVert$, the eigenvalues are $\dfrac{i \pm \sqrt{3}}{2}$, both of absolute value $1$.

$$A^\ast A = \begin{pmatrix}2 & -i\\i & 1\end{pmatrix}$$

has eigenvalues $\dfrac{3 \pm \sqrt{5}}{2}$.

If on the other hand hermitian symmetry was meant, then all eigenvalues are real, eigenvectors to different eigenvalues are orthogonal, and hence the operator norm is the largest absolute value of all eigenvalues.